# Listing the number of connected accessories with External Accessory in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, external-accessory

Using the External Accessory framework, or some other framework, is it possible to list the number of accessories connected to an iOS device?

I've been using `import ExternalAccessory` and then in a method trying to call one of the classes Apple lists. For example, it would seem that `connectedAccessories` would do this, but it comes back zero no matter what I connect or disconnect to the device. The code/app I have been using is simple. It is a `UIButton` that when pressed sends the number of connected devices to a `UILabel`.

If this is a duplicate or I've missed something, kindly point me in the right direction and I will delete this post.

The code I have is:

```
import UIKit
import ExternalAccessory

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var textDump: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var textButton: UIButton!

var messageText = "Initial View"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    view.backgroundColor = .black
    textDump.textColor = .white
    showText()
}

func showText(){
    textDump.text! = messageText
    textDump.textColor = .white
}

@IBAction func buttonPress(_ sender: Any){
    var newAccessory = EAAccessoryManager().connectedAccessories.count
    messageText = messageText + "\n Number of connected accessories: " + String(newAccessory)
    showText()
}
}
```

Comment: What accessory are you connecting?  `EAAccessoryManager()` is only relevant for MFi accessories connected over the lightning port or legacy Bluetooth.  It won't report standard accessories like handsfree kits etc.

Comment: Just a standard keyboard. Is there no way to list these types of devices? Also, what constitutes a MFi accessory?

Comment: No, a keyboard won't be reported.   An MFi accessory contains an MFi chip that is licensed under the [MFi Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/)

Comment: Ok. Is there another way to detect or list accessories that are not on the MFi program (such as a keyboard or other USB device)?

Comment: Not directly that I am aware of.  You can infer the existence of a hardware keyboard by the on-screen keyboard not appearing when a text field becomes the first responder (however you can trigger the on-screen keyboard from a hardware keyboard).  In general, USB devices are not supported by iOS.  You can use the camera connector to connect some USB devices.